# Read data from a COM port using TCP

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, serial-port

I'm using a [Moxa Serial Hub](http://www.moxa.com/product/nport_5650.htm) centralize some devices that communicate using RS-232 / NMEA protocol.

The serial hub is working as a TCP client, witch every time it receives data transmits it to a know IP/port in my machine.

[image: schema]

The problem is that I'm not receiving the data properly (I thought all I had to do was create a TCP server that accepts connections, and read the data as bytes, but that just gives me some weird characters)

I receive the bytes...but when converting to text... its just some weird characters, I'm missing some detail in this conversion.
so far I've tried:

```
byte[] b = new byte[1000];
int k = s.Receive(b);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b, 0, 1000));
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b));
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
   Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
```

all these 3 approaches write the same text...

Does any one know how to properly read the data in this cases?

Comment: So you actually get a connection request from the moxa hub and receive (wrong) data? Then it might be related to wrong serial port settings on the moxa device (probably the wrong baud rate)

Comment: are you sure that your data should be text (and not some raw byte array)?

Comment: I'm receiving it as an array of bytes, but I need to convert it to something I can use (NMEA protocol), so I need to convert it to text properly ...

Comment: This sounds like an encoding problem based on the fact you claim you recieved "wierd" characters. Are you able to verify the bytes you recieve/send perhaps are actually correct by hand?  So convert it.....What exactly is your question you have provided no code.

Comment: What bytes do you get, and what data did you expect to get?

Comment: Jan sent me in the right direction,it as actually a wrong baud rate I was using 4800, because I read it was a typical config [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183) after reading the manual I found this port uses 57600 baud rate. it Looks fine now :)

Comment: @Hans Passant: could you _please_ stop adding [Solved] to the title of questions? If the question has been answered in a comment or by the OP himself, add it as an answer instead. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-someone-elses-question

Comment: What is the specific GPS device you are you using?  Documenting that here might help some future user.  Many GPS devices use 4800bps, but apparently not all.

Comment: @dbasnett In my particular situation, was a ublox RCB-4H-0-000 board, it has 2 output COM ports, one uses 57600 and the other 9600 baud rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment provided the solution to the problem:

> So you actually get a connection request from the moxa hub and receive (wrong) data? Then it might be related to wrong serial port settings on the moxa device (probably the wrong baud rate) – Jan 2 hours ago

Indeed, the baud rate was wrong.